# React onChange event does not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux

The issue is onChange event does not fire in the input tag. I was using LinkedStateMixin to track input value before. Lately, I want to add onChange event to run some function then I removed LinkedStateMixin, but the onChange cannot fire. I tried to add e.stopPropagation() to setUsername(), but it is not working too. I tried other event such as onKeyDown, onClick, and ect. none of them can be fired. What is the problem?

```
var React = require('react');

var SessionActions = require('../../actions/session_actions');
var UserStore = require('../../stores/user_store');

var LogInForm = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      user: undefined,
      username: '',
      password: '',
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.token = UserStore.addListener(this.updateUserStore);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.token.remove();
  },

  updateUserStore: function() {
    this.setState({user: UserStore.all()});
    this.setState({username: ''});
    this.setState({password: ''});
  },

  setUsername: function(e) {
    console.log("Fired");
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    SessionActions.logIn({
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    });
    this.updateUserStore();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Log In</h4>
        <div> </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.setUsername} placeholder="Username" type="text"/>

          <input placeholder="Password" type="password"/>

          <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </form>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

module.exports = LogInForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function name from setUsername to handleUsername.

Answer (score 2):

I created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50952/) with the code you posted and, despite the obvious warnings, the onchange event is fired. So I guess there is something else wrong with your code.

Does the component even render? Could you provide a fiddle where it is not working so I can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried your fiddle, it is working in the fiddle but I do not understand why it does not working on mine which is exactly same what I post. I am using chrome, and the form can render but the onChange does not fire. I am using webpack, do you think it will cause the problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a webpack problem because the form is being rendered. Open chrome dev tools and see if there is any warning or error printed in the console.

Comment: I finally solve this problem! I change the handler function' name from setUsername() to handleUsername(), then it works fine! Do you know why this is happened?